# firebase: my dinosaurs are not ordered by height

Tags: firebase

trying a few tutorial things out with the Firebase REST interface. The tutorials says this should sort my dinosaurs by height, but they seem to still be sorted by key (name). It appears that the example is probably not a good one (since I'm getting a dictionary back, it *can't* be sorted).

Am I misreading the docs? Why would they use this as an example if it does not work?

```
$ curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com?dinosaurs.json?orderBy="height"&print=pretty'
{
  "bruhathkayosaurus" : {
    "appeared" : -70000000,
    "height" : 25,
    "length" : 44,
    "order" : "saurischia",
    "vanished" : -70000000,
    "weight" : 135000
  },
  "lambeosaurus" : {
    "appeared" : -76000000,
    "height" : 2.1,
    "length" : 12.5,
    "order" : "ornithischia",
    "vanished" : -75000000,
    "weight" : 5000
  },
  "linhenykus" : {
    "appeared" : -85000000,
    "height" : 0.6,
    "length" : 1,
    "order" : "theropoda",
    "vanished" : -75000000,
    "weight" : 3
  },
  "pterodactyl" : {
    "appeared" : -150000000,
    "height" : 0.6,
    "length" : 0.8,
    "order" : "pterosauria",
    "vanished" : -148500000,
    "weight" : 2
  },
  "stegosaurus" : {
    "appeared" : -155000000,
    "height" : 4,
    "length" : 9,
    "order" : "ornithischia",
    "vanished" : -150000000,
    "weight" : 2500
  },
  "triceratops" : {
    "appeared" : -68000000,
    "height" : 3,
    "length" : 8,
    "order" : "ornithischia",
    "vanished" : -66000000,
    "weight" : 11000
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be buggy... it does not work for any key...

Comment: The ordering parameters in the REST API are only really useful in conjunction with other parameters that query the data (`limitToFirst`, `limitToLast`, `startAt`, `endAt`, `equalTo` etc.) and only help specify the results set you get back from the server. The actual results returned cannot be ordered precisely because of the limitations you mentioned around JSON objects, and as such need to be ordered client-side.

Comment: pity that the documentation has an example that doesn't work: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html uses`curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="height"&print=pretty'` as an example.

Comment: That example indeed doesn't make sense. I've made a note to fix it.